# java - add random objects to array random

Tags: java

I have the object `Classe` has a list of rooms, and i have a list of rooms predefined `roomsList`, i want to add 2 rooms randomly from the list `roomsList` in each `Classe` where a room added to a `Classe` can't be added again in an other `Classe`.
for example, if i have 3 classes and 7 rooms, each Classe will have 2 rooms, and 1 room will remain.

```
List<Classe> classes = classRepository.findAll();

for (Classe cl : classes) {
  List<Room> roomsList = Arrays.asList(new Room1(), newRoom2(), new Room3(), new Room4(), new Room5(), new Room6(), new Room7());
  if (roomsList.size() >=  classes.size() * 2) {
    cl.setRooms(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? I hope I understood well what you wanted.

```
Random rand = new Random();
List<Classe> classes = classRepository.findAll();
List<Rooms> rooms = roomsRepository.findAll();
int roomsPerClass= Math.floor(rooms.size()/classes.size());
for (Classe classe:classes) {
    for(int count=0; count<roomsPerClass) {
        Room room = rooms.get(rand.nextInt(rooms.size()));
        rooms.remove(room);
        classe.add(room);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
List<Classe> classes = classRepository.findAll();

List<Room> roomsList = Arrays.asList(
    new Room1(), newRoom2(), new Room3(), new Room4(), 
    new Room5(), new Room6(), new Room7());
Collections.shuffle(roomsList);
for (Classe cl : classes) {
  if (roomsList.size() >=  2) {
    // Take first two rooms from shuffled list...
    cl.setRooms(roomsList[0], roomsList[1]);
    // ... then remove them from the list so they can't be assigned again
    roomsList.remove(0);
    roomsList.remove(0);
  }
}
```